# Edit distance between two pandas columns

Tags: python, string, pandas, nlp, nltk

I have a pandas DataFrame consisting of two columns of strings. I would like to create a third column containing the Edit Distance of the two columns.

```
from nltk.metrics import edit_distance    
df['edit'] = edit_distance(df['column1'], df['column2'])
```

For some reason this seems to go to some sort of infinite loop in the sense that it remains unresponsive for quite some time and then I have to terminate it manually.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The nltk's `edit_distance` function is for comparing pairs of strings. If you want to compute the edit distance between corresponding pairs of strings, `apply` it separately to each row's strings like this:

```
results = df.apply(lambda x: edit_distance(x["column1"], x["column2"]), axis=1)
```

Or like this (probably a little more efficient), to avoid including the irrelevant columns of the dataframe:

```
results = df.loc[:, ["column1", "column2"]].apply(lambda x: edit_distance(*x), axis=1)
```

To add the results to your dataframe, you'd use it like this:

```
df["distance"] = df.loc[:, ["column1","column2"]].apply(lambda x: edit_distance(*x), axis=1)
```

Comment: I suppose this would work but the DataFrame has more than 2 columns. I only care about taking the edit distance of two of them so this code fails. Can I give some other value to `axis` other than 0 and 1, i.e. can I specify column numbers?

Comment: Well, you did say "dataframe consisting of **two** columns of strings" :-) Edited my answer. The `axis` argument is about the direction of iteration (columns or rows), so it's not what you need to tweak here.

Comment: Totally my fault! Thanks a lot for the rapid and complete response! (-:

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer has solved your problem, please click on the big check mark to "accept" it as the solution and mark your question resolved.

Comment: @alexis is it supposed to take a lot of time on a data frame with 45,000 rows? just 2 cols I want to calculate the distance.

Comment: Well, these are pairwise comparisons so once you subtract start-up time, it will take 45,000 times as long as it takes to compare one pair of strings. In other words it's linear on the size of the input, nothing to worry about. But why ask me, @Jack? Haven't you tried the code yet?

Comment: hi, this seems useful but I was wondering, what do I need to change in the code in order for this to work for jaccard distance as well? When I currently try running for jaccard distance, it gives me a KeyError: 'string', 'occured at index Text')

Comment: @alexis How would you use lambdas expression when you have to compare two fields of different length between two different dataframes? I am currently having that problem..

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The edit_distance() function can compare two strings of different length. If it's your columns that are of different lengths, what do you want to compare the unmatched cells to?