# How do I calculate the Levenshtein distance between two Pandas DataFrame columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to calculate the Levenshtein distance between two Pandas columns but I'm getting stuck Here is the [library](https://pypi.org/project/textdistance/) I'm using. Here is a minimal, reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
from textdistance import levenshtein

attempts = [['passw0rd', 'pasw0rd'],
            ['passwrd', 'psword'],
            ['psw0rd', 'passwor']]

df=pd.DataFrame(attempts, columns=['password', 'attempt'])
```

```
   password  attempt
0  passw0rd  pasw0rd
1   passwrd   psword
2    psw0rd  passwor
```

My poor attempt:

```
df.apply(lambda x: levenshtein.distance(*zip(x['password'] + x['attempt'])), axis=1)
```

This is how the function works. **It takes two strings as arguments:**

```
levenshtein.distance('helloworld', 'heloworl')
```

```
Out[1]: 2
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636848/is-it-possible-to-do-fuzzy-match-merge-with-python-pandas/56315491#56315491) post by Erfan, it goes over how to implement the fuzzy wuzzy package which implements the levenshtein distance algo to match words.

Comment: Sounds like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376863/adding-calculated-columns-to-a-dataframe-in-pandas) might help?

Comment: @Datanovice I don't think it's about the Levenshtein function (Since the question already includes an import to calculate that), but about how to apply it to a DF.

Comment: When you use `apply`, each row is returned as `x` to your `lambda` as a `Series`. Why do you zip them? just pass them as `x['password']` etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Edit distance between two pandas columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892617/edit-distance-between-two-pandas-columns)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, is there a reason you don't like the lambda expression? This works to me:

```
import pandas as pd
from textdistance import levenshtein

attempts = [['passw0rd', 'pasw0rd'],
            ['passwrd', 'psword'],
            ['psw0rd', 'passwor'],
            ['helloworld', 'heloworl']]

df=pd.DataFrame(attempts, columns=['password', 'attempt'])

df.apply(lambda x: levenshtein.distance(x['password'],  x['attempt']), axis=1)
```

out:

```
0    1
1    3
2    4
3    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: or with `map`: `df.assign(distance=[*map(levenshtein.distance, df.password, df.attempt)])`